# Continuity on the diagonal of a certain function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have just started my course in multivariable calculus and I am doing several exercises to practice. In particular, I have not very clear how to do this one, so any help will be welcome.

> Given $\Psi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$, then the map defined by
> $$F_{\beta}(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
>              \dfrac{\Psi(x)-\Psi(y)}{|x-y|^\beta} & x\neq y \\
>              \\ 0  & x=y
>              \end{array}
>    \right.$$
> is continuous for $\beta\in (0,1)) $ but not for $\beta=1$.

My attempt:

Out of the diagonal $x=y$ the  vector field is continuous. Furthermore,
by mean value theorem, we know that $|F_{\beta}(x,y)|\leq{M}|x-y|^{1-\beta}$, so we can concluded that $F_\beta$ is continuouus when $\beta \in (0,1)$.

However I don't know how to prove that $F_1$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\Psi \equiv 0$ the function $F_{\beta} $ is continuous for any $\beta$, so we cannot prove that $F_{\beta} $ can never be continuous for $\beta=1$.  But we can given an example to show that $F_{\beta} $ need not be continuous when $\beta=1$. For this take $d=1$ and take $\Psi$ such that the function is equal to the identity function  in some interval around $0$. In this case $F_{\beta} $ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.